# Replace Element After 3 Clicks With Cookie Logging [.load]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, element

I coded simple jquery code to replace a specific element with urls code after 3 clicks. After it has exceeded 3 clicks it replaces the element with urls code. Using .load(""). But after, I refresh the page the element returns back to its default state, unreplaced. How could, I make webserver remember the change. Whether in the database or in Cookie, sessionStorage, localStorage.

```
var count = 0;

$(document).ready( function () {
    $("#id-2").on("click", function(){
    count++;
    if(count == 3)
        $("#id-2").load("yoinkexecutor2.html");
    });
});
```

All, I want is the element to stay replaced with urls code after clicking on it 3 times and not changing back after refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use localStorage or Cookies.

```
var count = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count"), 10) || 0;
function loadMyPage() {
    if (count >= 3)
        $("#id-2").load("yoinkexecutor2.html");
    }
}

$(document).ready( function () {
    loadMyPage();
    $("#id-2").on("click", function() {
        localStorage.setItem("count", count += 1);
        loadMyPage();
    });
});
```

Remember localStorage (and Cookies) only store values as string, hence parseInt.
Also it will keep loading your .html page after subsequent clicks, you might want to remove the click handler, or remove the #id-2 element.

Comment: thanks for helping, I find it interesting values are stored in string and thought you use stringify for that aswell, appreciate it.

Comment: If you are storing an object or array, then yes you need to stringify the value first.